# using .NET Core 2 for webapi and Angular for ui on same linux machine

Tags: angular, azure, nginx, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to configure a Linux server (on Azure or AWS) that can host my application. I want  build back-end services (WebApi) in .NET core , and build my UI with Angular (may use Nodejs) . I want to start doing it on one linux instance and may be split them when traffic increases. Can this be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Nginx as a load balancer for different route something

```
localhost/admin
localhost/category
```

and can pass location in nginx config

```
location /admin/ {
rewrite ^/admin^/ /$1 break;
proxy_pass http://10.128.1.2;
```

}